# Hey, it's a puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

You Just Joined Puzzling SE. You are about to ask your first question on puzzling SE, but you face an emergency. You have the Reputation Bonus, Therefore you have 101 Reputation. You forget About Puzzling SE, and a 100 years later, your great grand child opens your account. If Stack Exchange Worked Like the real world, He/She would have found out that your rep (On Puzzling SE) has in a way decreased.

Find Out what affected your Reputation Points.

RULES:

1. I don't know if you can lose the reputation bonus, but that's not the case.
2. What I mean by reputation is the value of your points, not how other people think about you and stuff...

Comment: I think this question is too broad, I have like 20 possibilities in my head.

Comment: @Doomenik First Answer At Least One Possiblity?? :)

Comment: Added some, can add more if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it´s too broad I give some possibilities:

> 1. Starting from any year after they punish inactivity. Like 1 Point for every year inactivity. 
>
>
>  2. There's a huge wave of spam upcoming and they decide to set the reputation limit for new questions to something bigger. Your 101 Reputation is less worthy.
>
>
>  3. The borg queen takes over the world and decides to throw away the numeric system and instead uses an alphabetical system (a=0, b=1, c=2...). So your reputation is only *bab* worth.
>
>  4. Nobody uses the internet anymore so having a reputation on an old website is nothing worth.

Comment: Okay, None Of them Are What I was looking for, but you are right, too broad.

Comment: So I'll give you a correct and open a new question

Answer (score 3):

> When you faced the emergency, instead of clicking the close button you downvoted one answer hence losing 1 rep point.